# How can i format correctly the "Size" param at Get-Partition?

Tags: powershell

When i use get-partition i get something like that:

```
PartitionNumber                                   Size Type
---------------                                   ---- ----
1                                            931.51 GB IFS
```

As you can see, the Size is correctly formatted with GB behind.

When I use:

```
get-partition | select Size

         Size
         ----
    104857600
```

i get the size in the wrong format.
is it possible to get it like the upper one without math functions?

Comment: How does partition number correlates with size again? I'm lost

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon its the standard output from the command get-partition or not?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print the sizes expressed in GB with two decimal places, with suffix  `GB`, do the following:

```sh
Get-Partition | ForEach-Object { '{0:N2} GB' -f ($_.Size / 1gb) }
```

<sup>If you also want a column header, use `Format-Table` with a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) as follows: 

`Format-Table @{ Name='Size'; Expression={ '{0:N2} GB' -f ($_.Size / 1gb) } }`. You could use the same technique with `Select-Object`, but since *for-display formatting* is the goal here, that isn't necessary.</sup>

If you want to *auto-scale* the sizes (using simulated input objects to demonstrate, via PowerShell's number-literal suffixes such as `kb`, which are multiples of 1024):

```sh
@{ Size = 42 }, 
@{ Size = 42.1kb }, 
@{ Size = 42.2mb }, 
@{ Size = 42.3gb }, 
@{ Size = 42.4tb },
@{ Size = 42.4pb } |
  ForEach-Object { 
    $decimalPlaces = 2
    $scaledSize = switch ($_.Size) {
      { $_ -ge 1pb } { $_ / 1pb; $suffix='PB'; break }
      { $_ -ge 1tb } { $_ / 1tb; $suffix='TB'; break }
      { $_ -ge 1gb } { $_ / 1gb; $suffix='GB'; break }
      { $_ -ge 1mb } { $_ / 1mb; $suffix='MB'; break }
      { $_ -ge 1kb } { $_ / 1kb; $suffix='KB'; break }
      default        { $_; $suffix='B'; $decimalPlaces = 0 }
    }

    "{0:N${decimalPlaces}} $suffix" -f $scaledSize
  }
```

Output:

```
42 B
42.10 KB
42.20 MB
42.30 GB
42.40 TB
42.40 PB
```

Note: The auto-scaling code above is essentially a more readable formulation of what PowerShell does in its default [for-display formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/format/formatting-file-overview) for the output objects emitted by `Get-Partition`, via their `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#MSFT_Partition` ETS type name; specifically, the code used is:

```sh
$size = $_.Size;
$postfixes = @( "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB" )
for ($i=0; $size -ge 1024 -and $i -lt $postfixes.Length; $i++) { $size = $size / 1024; }
return "" + [System.Math]::Round($size,2) + " " + $postfixes[$i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is using math to round the number ok?

```
Get-Partition | Select DriveLetter, PartitionNumber, @{Label = "Size"; Expression = { [math]::round($_.Size / 1gb, 2) } }
```

Comment: I tried   `Get-Partition  | Select-Object -Property DiskNumber, PartitionNumber, DriveLetter, @{Label = "Size"; Expression = { [math]::round($_.Size / 1gb, 2) } } | Format-List` but my Output is: `DiskNumber      : 3
PartitionNumber : 1
DriveLetter     :
Size            : 104857600

DiskNumber      : 3
PartitionNumber : 2
DriveLetter     :
Size            : 16777216

DiskNumber      : 3
PartitionNumber : 3
DriveLetter     : G
Size            : 499443040256
`

Comment: i shortened the output, i have got a few partitions :D

Comment: in the console does it work, but in  the script not, thats crazy